# Software to capture 3d geometry?

Tags: software-rec, opengl, 3d-graphics, capture, direct3d

**Programs I found**

I found these programs to capture OpenGL 3D scene :

- [3D Ripper, OpenGL and D3D geometry capture](http://www.deep-shadows.com/hax/3DRipperDX.htm), there are some [solved problems with 3D Ripper](http://www.tombraiderforums.com/showthread.php?t=156131)
- [GLIntercept captures OpenGL function calls](http://glintercept.nutty.org/)
- [OpenGL Extractor captures 3d geometry; should work as plugin for GLIntercept](http://www.brothersoft.com/ogle-18658.html)
- [another tool to capture OpenGL 3D data](http://members.chello.at/~alexan/)
- **EDIT**: There is also [HijackGL which changes how a scene is rendered](http://www.cs.wisc.edu/graphics/Gallery/HijackGL/) so it probably can be used to capture geometry; it is backed up by a academic paper; *it is just just a nice program, not related to what I want i think (or it would might be hard to change it to be for what I want, because it would require programming).*

3D Ripper captures geometry, textures and shaders. OpenGL Extractor captures just geometry ...

**General questions about such programs**

What is Your experience with these programs? Which of these programs would You recommmend? Do You know other such programs? Were there any problems with them, or are there problems with them in general? Are there programs which work best overall, or is it specific to certain 3d applications?

**What I need to do?**

I am looking to program which can capture 3d geometry for study purposes. And also for a program to capture 3D animation (frames of 3d animation).

I tried only 3D Ripper because application I try to capture data from is on Direct 3D. 3D Ripper works with at least Direct 3D 9, this application has Direct 3D 6. Are there applications which work with older version of Direct 3D?

Thank You very much. :)

(I was verbose in link names because I want them to be indexed better by search engines.)

Comment: directly from your link: "3D Ripper DX supports only DirectX 6.x, 8.x and 9.x applications"

Comment: Thanks. :) I apologize for my mistake. It seems support that D3D 6 support is in beta, so that might be reason why it is not working ...

Answer (score 1):

The link to OGLE is wrong — it points to some sort of screensaver. OGLE works as a plugin to GLInterceptor and allegedly dumps all OpenGL geometry properly, but OGLE's creators, Eyebeam Research, seemed to have dumped the site where the project was hosted (http://ogle.eyebeamresearch.org/, which isn't replying since 2010). You can still download it using the [Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20100709233104/http://ogle.eyebeamresearch.org/) but I haven't tested it yet.